# .htaccess Rewrite direct file access

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been looking all over and I can't find a solution that works for me.

I'm trying to redirect http://example.com/files/file.ext -> http://example.com/users/documents/file.ext

No matter what I try when I got directly to the file it downloads it. The GET request for the file doesn't show in any of my apache logs either. I have logging on debug.

[Edit]
The files I'm trying to download are of various types including ppt, pdf, xls, zip, doc, etc. I want to rewrite the filename to the end of the new URI. I am also using CodeIgniter so /users/documents/ is a RESTy uri.

Anyone have a fix?

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteBase /


    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php


    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [N]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/files/ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^/files/(.*)$ /users/documents/$1 [L,R=301]


    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you tried moving your `/files/` rules above the ones that rewrite everything to `index.php`?

Comment: I just tried it. I had before, but not with that exact rule. It still just downloads the file.

Comment: What do you mean by it "just downloads the file". Is it HTML but not being rendered? Do you have a handler assigned for the extension ".ext"?

Comment: It's a variety of file types such as pdf, ppt, xls, zip, docx, etc. I want to take the file being requested and put it at the end of the new URI.

Answer (score 2):

If this is in your htaccess file, try replacing this line:

```
RewriteRule ^/files/(.*)$ /users/documents/$1 [L,R=301]
```

with:

```
RewriteRule ^/?files/(.*)$ /users/documents/$1 [L,R=301]
```

And putting the condition and rule before any of the `index.php` routing rules.

Comment: No change in functionality. I moved the condition and your revised rewrite rule to just below "RewriteBase /"

Comment: @Scone maybe the condition is failing? `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/files/ [NC]` It looks fine to me, maybe also add the `?` to the leading slash (though it shouldn't need it) so it's `^/?files/`?

Comment: I'll try that. What does the '?' do?

Comment: @Scone Means that the `/` preceeding the `?` is optional

Comment: If i go to http://example.com/files/ it redirects me to /users/documents/, but not if i got to example.com/files/filename.pdf

Comment: @Scone Well, you also could try just getting rid of the rule and use mod_alias: `Redirect 301 /files /users/documents`

Answer (score 0):

I went to http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ and tested my rewrite rules.
It said the RewriteCond wasn't matching anything, but when I remove the rule it matches.

Working Rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?files/(.*)$ /users/documents/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Moving this to the top of the htaccess file fixes the issue.